# Which file of wordpress manage plugins functionalities?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

Which file of wordpress manage the plugins functionalities. For example if a have to insert another rule in a plugin functionality where i go to modify?

Comment: Modifying core WP files is considered **extremely** bad practice and almost never required to accomplish things. Please add some details on what exactly you want done so you get good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should never be a case where you edit the core. Filters and actions were created so plugin developers could navigate the intricacies of Wordpress wihtout touching core files. You should reference the following:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

There are quite a few undocumented filters that I find when viewing WP core. If you do go to core, I would look for a filter that's being used in the area you wish to alter Wordpress rather than change the file outright.